# Can you add data to a datagrid with no data source?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, controls

I have a DataGrid with 5 template columns,

However when I try and add some dynamically created controls into the grid, it fails, as there are no rows.

-Can i add a blank row in and use that? and how?
-Or any other way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you have to bind to a data source.  But it's easy enough to create your own `DataTable` and insert a row into it with some dummy info.

```
//pseudo code:

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("column1");
dt.Columns.Add(dc);
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["column1"] = "value1";
dt.Rows.AddNew(dr);

myDataGrid.DataSource = dt;
myDataGrid.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are using an unbound DataGridView, you can create new rows and then add them to DataGridView.  Your question referred to DataGrid, but you tagged it for DataGridView.

```
// Sample code to add a new row to an unbound DataGridView
DataGridViewRow YourNewRow = new DataGridViewRow();

YourNewRow.CreateCells(YourDataGridView);
YourNewRow.Cells[0].Value = "Some value";
YourNewRow.Cells[1].Value = "Another value";

YourDataGridView.Rows.Add(YourNewRow);
```